# Django creating foreign key references to the wrong tables on database creation

Tags: django, sqlite, django-2.1

I wiped out the database on my Django app to start again. I did this by deleting the database file and existing migrations and then re-running `makemigrations` and `migrate`. I of course backed up the database first.

I soon ran into an issue; upon submitting a form I was informed that `The table 'topics__old' does not exist.` which I thought odd as I have named all my tables and that is not one of them. Here are the relevent models:

```
class Topic(models.Model, FormatDateMixin):

    topic_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)

    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'topics'

class TopicUpdate(models.Model, FormatDateMixin):
    update_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)

    original_topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'topic_updates'
```

I checked out the database files for the old working version and the current version and I found the following:

Original Table:
`CREATE TABLE "topic_updates" ("update_id" char(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ... "original_topic_id" char(32) NOT NULL REFERENCES "topics" ("topic_id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, ...`

New Table:
`CREATE TABLE "topic_updates" ("update_id" char(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ... "original_topic_id" char(32) NOT NULL REFERENCES "topics__old" ("topic_id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, ...`

As you can see when creating the database Django is appending `__old` to the table name when referencing foreign keys, which the causes errors in the application as `topics__old` does not exist.

I have tried removing all `__pycache__` folders, deleting all migration files, re-running `makemigrations` and `migrate --run-syncdb`. None of this has fixed the issue.

It should be noted it does indeed create the table `topics` and the forms related to the `topics` table work as expected. Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you also delete the rows in all of the migration history table?

Comment: this happens when I delete the database and run migrations from scratch aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some grepping and found `__old` in `django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py` which led me to find the root cause.

Turns out this was caused by an update to SQLite, Django have pushed a fix in:
https://github.com/django/django/commit/894cb13779e6d092974c873bd2cf1452554d2e06

> SQLite 3.26 changed the behaviour of table and column renaming operations to
>   repoint foreign key references even if foreign key checks are disabled.
>   This makes the workarounds in place to simulate this behaviour unnecessary on
>   SQLite 3.26+.

However this update does not seem to have made its way onto pypi or ubuntu/debian repos as of yet despite being over two weeks old, so I had to remove my instance of django and `pip install` from the git repo.